# QBWC ItemQueryRq error

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, qbxml, qbwc

I am using Web Connector to add/edit items in QuickBooks If item already exist then I am updating that item and then generate sales order. I have a one customer compiling that sales order is not generating. I checked company file item is already in QuickBooks but it's not able to find that item and give me error that "The query request has not been fully completed. There was a required element ("Frymaster:106-1479SP@D") that could not be found in QuickBooks." Parent item is Frymaster and I am able to find that item.

All the existing Inventory sub items are not able to find. If I create new Inventory items on that company file then I look that that items it's working perfectly fine but for existing items search is not working. When I tried to add that item then it's say item is already exist. Even in sales order gives me error

Item is there but some how it's gives me error that "The query request has not been fully completed. There was a required element ("Frymaster:106-1479SP@D") that could not be found in QuickBooks." How to resolve that error?

Answer (score 0):

Enable verbose logging in QB and QBWC and see if it gives you any more information in the logs. https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/177198-troubleshooting-sdk-issues

Also, make sure you are encoding the request. I don't know if the '@' could be causing a problem.

Comment: I have tried to enabled verbose mode, but I couldn't find any error info. '@' is not an issue because for new items special char s working fine.

Comment: I have tried to enabled verbose mode, but I couldn't find any error info. '@' is not an issue because for new items special char s working fine. Not all items are not searchable, but whatever in company file I have and used in all transaction those are not working. But if I add new items it creates new parent and sub item then it's working.